# Выборка с сортировкой

Tags: mysql

Нужно сделать выборку: выбрать последние записи и только у каждого пользователя всего одну.
Пишу данный SQL:

```
SELECT `id`, `to_id`, `owner_id`, `timestamp_created`, `type`, `text` 
FROM `messages` 
WHERE `owner_id` = :owner_id 
GROUP BY `to_id` DESС
```

Но выбираются первые записи, а мне нужны последние.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT `id`, `to_id`, `owner_id`, `timestamp_created`, `type`, `text` 
FROM `messages`    
WHERE `id` IN (
    SELECT MAX(`id`) 
    FROM `messages`
    WHERE `owner_id` = :owner_id 
    GROUP BY `to_id`
  ) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное

Comment: @Timur если ответ помог - можно нажать галочку рядом с ответом и стрелочку вверх :)